# Typescript compile error with latest antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Running `npm tsc` with the latest [antd](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design) version returns several errors.

```
node_modules/antd/lib/tooltip/placements.d.ts:16:73 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '_rc-trigger@5.2.1@rc-trigger' or its corresponding type declarations.

16 export default function getPlacements(config: PlacementsConfig): import("_rc-trigger@5.2.1@rc-trigger").BuildInPlacements;
```

antd version `4.11.1`

Any fixes/ workarounds?

Comment: if it's a react project why you use npm tsc ?

Comment: Yes it's a react  project. `npm tsc` runs as a ci quality stage.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue PR: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/pull/29029

If you want to suppress the error set `skipLibCheck: true` in `ts.config`